# How would you find the number of injective functions of $f:A \to B$ such that $f(a_1) = f(b_1)$ is satisfied?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say you had $A = \{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B= \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, with cardinality $|A| = 2$ and $|B| = 3$, how would you find the # of injective functions of $f: A \to B$ such that $f(a_1) = b_1$ is satisfied?

Also, what exactly does the $f(a_1) = b_1$ mean?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your function $f$ is uniquely defined by its action on $a_1$ and $a_2$. Since $f(a_1)$ is fixed, we now can only choose $f(a_2)$. How many choices do we have? Since $f$ is injective, we cannot have $f(a_2)=b_1$, hence we only have two possible choices:$b_2, b_3$.

So the answer is 2.

Also, I don't really see any deep meaning in $f(a_1)=b_1$ besides the obvious.

Comment: How is f(a1) fixed?

Comment: Your problem statement directly states that $f(a_1)=b_1$, thus, we cannot choose the value of $f(a_1)$; i.e. it is fixed.